# How to get the Name of the Class a Function is in with Python 3.11

Tags: python, function, class, python-3.11

So, i have a class like this:

```
class Test:
    def test69():
        print(classname)
```

and That function (test69()) prints the Name of the Class that it is in.
Like, a Function is in a Class, and the Function prints the Name of the Class that it is in to the Console.

I am working on Python 3.11, if that Helps any.

Does anyone know how to do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It is available via the [`__class__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#executing-the-class-body) reference:

```
class Test:
    def test69():
        print(__class__.__name__)
```

Comment: Is a function declared in this way static? I compared the output with one wrapped with `staticmethod` and seem the same

Comment: Nope, it is not the same. A static method could be called on an instance like `Test().test69()`, but this function could not be called in that way, only by `Test.test69()`. To see the difference you have to bypass the descriptor protocol with e.g. `object.__getattribute__(Test, "test69")`.